# Our web server hung up during the night

Tags: web-server, web-hosting

Is there any cost effective solution for us to keep our website alive ?
Please advice me the direction.  Besides, it's too expensive for use to buy a cluster.
Thanks in advance !

Comment: Can you elaborate on what you mean by "hanged up"? Did it crash due to a lack of available resources?

Comment: More info is needed for anyone to give an semblance of a reasonable answer. What OS/webserver/language? What caused the web server to hang? Any relevant log messages? How much traffic was hitting your server when it crashed? Did it run out of memory? Unless you have a very high amount of traffic, it's quite unlikely that you'd need a cluster of any sort.

Comment: I don't know why , i tried to look up in the event log, but can not  find the whole day's log.

Comment: Hooligan - well if you're unable to provide more info, you're not going to get an answer.

Comment: The only cost-effective way to make a web site highly available is to outsource your hosting to a provider that has already invested in a fully redundant datacenter.  Unfortunately, solving the immediate problem will do nothing to make the service reliable over the long term.  Fortunately, you have many very affordable options to operate your web service off-site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is Windows: 
If the service actually failed, Windows has a tab in the service properties called "Recovery", there you can specify what to do if the service fails. You can specify for first, second, and "subsequent". You may want to tell it to restart the service the first time, notify you and restart the second time.

This won't help if Windows didn't report the service as failed, or if Windows itself locked up. In that case you may want to look into "siteuptime" to get notifications when your site dies.

If this is Linux, look into http://mmonit.com/monit/ to watch for a response from your webserver. It can restart services and run external scripts as necessary to keep everything online.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you have your own datacenter, please don't try to host your web site in-house if you care about reliability.  Even if you did have the money to set up a cluster, you would still need redundant power including battery backup and generators, redundant internet connections, your own IP address space to provide for redundant routing, your own team of network engineers to provide 24x7 monitoring... you get the idea.

If you need your web site to be highly available *and* you don't happen to have your own datacenter, you need to outsource your web hosting.  In the world of web hosting, you have almost unlimited choices, and I am personally familiar with only some of them.  One established company that provides reasonably priced, very reliable web hosting is [Pair Networks](http://www.pair.com), which operates a datacenter with fully redundant power and upstream bandwidth as well as 24x7 monitoring and support.

I'm sure that there are many other very dependable options, and perhaps others can make some additional recommendations based on their own experience.  Just beware of companies that offer "unlimited" anything, as this usually comes at the expense of dependability.